# Websphere Uploading EAR file, Heap issue

Tags: java, websphere, heap-memory, ear

First to say that I am really new with java and websphere and so my knowledge is very low.

I am trying to install Application from `Application Types -> WebSphere enterprise applications`

So after I click Install and choose my EAR file to upload and go Next, the Websphere just stuck and it's not responding anymore.

The CPU usage of the Websphere process goes up to 100% and I have to kill it and start Websphere again.

The error which I found in the logs is:

```
FFDC Exception:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError SourceId:com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.queryNames ProbeId:284 Reporter:javax.management.ObjectName@44376c54
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:295)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1135)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.writeObject(ObjectName.java:1263)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1020)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1502)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1555)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1516)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.ClientAccessor.request(ClientAccessor.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorClient.sendReceive(IPCConnectorClient.java:484)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorClient.queryNames(IPCConnectorClient.java:828)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminClientImpl.queryNames(AdminClientImpl.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.queryNames(AdminServiceImpl.java:684)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.status.AbstractStatusCache.getMBean(AbstractStatusCache.java:672)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.status.DeploymentManagerStatusCache.requestReport(DeploymentManagerStatusCache.java:336)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.status.DeploymentManagerStatusCache.requestReport(DeploymentManagerStatusCache.java:368)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.status.DeploymentManagerStatusCache.addToCache(DeploymentManagerStatusCache.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.status.DeploymentManagerStatusCache.childAdded(DeploymentManagerStatusCache.java:921)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.RoutingTable$AddChildThread.run(RoutingTable.java:1561)
```

I have there two clusters. Each cluster has two members. And I am trying to set up application with one of the clusters.

In each member of the cluster under settings `Java and Process Management -> Process definition -> Java Virtual Machine` are set next settings for heap:

```
Maximum heap size 
2048     MB
Initial heap size 
1024     MB
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue.

Comment: I would go to the IBM support. It is definitively not a normal behaviour.

Comment: Did you try to run your application in another app-server like tomee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having clusters, you are using Network deployment edition. In that case installation is done via Deployment manager. You need to increase heap size for deployment manager JVM. In the web admin console go to `System administration > Deployment manager` and there you should also have that `Java and Process Management` option. Increase heap sizes, restart dmgr and then reinstall application. You may need to increase heap sizes for node agents also, but start with Dmgr.

Comment: Yes, that's what I already did, but didn't have time to post the answer. Thank you